# r package: CFA and missing data

Tags: missing-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I am running confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) with `r`. As I have several missing observations, I get two series of results, on "used" (152) and "total" observations (246). How is the total calculated? Which of the two results should I use for the analysis?

Comment: Usually such packages will have a documentation in which methods and formulas are explained. Maybe it's the case also for this one?

Comment: What package are you using to run your analysis?

Comment: What do you mean by "two series of results"?